# SOQL for related objects in Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql

I'm querying an object(Custom_Obj_A) and some other fields from lookup object(Custom_Obj_B) using soql. These fields are then stored in Map<Id,Custom_Obj_A)>. I also want to utilize the fields from Custom_obj_B but the map only stores fields from Custom_obj_A (which is as expected). Is there a way to also store the fields of custom_obj_B ?. As of now, i'm looping through the query and adding the fields to Custom_obj_b list. Looking for a better option on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your query and iteration code? It makes it easier to answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `System.debug` to check the map values, you should be aware that child and parent relationships aren't printed out. The values are there, you just need to access them as normal:

```
// Parent
myMap.get(someRecordId).CustomObjectB__r.SomeField; 
// Child
myMap.get(someRecordId).CustomIbjectB__r.size();
```